# Prevent javascript in Innovaeditor

Tags: javascript, php, text-editor

I have integrated InnovaEditor in my project from where admin can enter html code to show on site.

My question is I want to prevent user to insert javascript event in html of editor.

For ex. if user add Mouse Over Here

Then onmouseover event should be removed. This feature is available in tinymce but not in innovaeditor. TinyMCE will remove events while user add code in html mode.

Can anyone help me out for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huhh.. I have figured out the event on which I can use regex to clean html code.

I am using onSelectionChanged event of Innovaeditor.

```
oEdit1.onSelectionChanged=function(){ 
  var html = oEdit1.getXHTMLBody();
  html = html.replace(/ on\w+="[^"]*"/g, '');
  html = html.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '');
  oEdit1.putHTML(html); 
};
```

Same script used with form validation on submit.

This code will remove script tag and all events from html code.